# Create FFMPEG Stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm building an FFMPEG stream in iOS that should convert any file type to wav and send it to an [http stream](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http)

```
ffmpeg -i "/path/to/audio/track.suffix" -vn -strict -2 -acodec pcm_u8 -f wav -listen 1 -seekable 1 http://localhost:8090/restream.wav
```

I posted a question to the ffmpeg user list and someone said:

> You are not sending valid wav files like this.

Can anyone help me to see what's wrong with this ffmpeg cmd?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cant see why this command should send invalid wav files. I thik you can safely use this. But why dont you just try it out ?